# How to pass parameter from D365 portal to workflow/action?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-portals

I am using the Integrated Portals coming with D365. I have an entity list and I've put a date-picker and a submit button in the page. I want to update the records inside the entity list with the date that the users selects from the date picker.

My problem is that I do not know how to pass the date picker value from the portal to the workflow (or somebody suggested using Actions).

Comment: Are you using an entity form for that page?

Comment: No, it's an entity list because the update action needs to be done on a selection of the records not all of them. So we introduced checkboxes next to the records and only the ones ticked need to be updated.

Comment: You have to start reading the basic of [web api for crm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx). After that you need to make the request with something like [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you don't want to use the native update.

Comment: Sorry - don't have a lot of experience using D365 Portals, but I couldn't find how to use the Web API from portal web page to update CRM.

Can you point me to some documentation of how to do it or how to the native update from the new integrated portals?

Thank you again

Comment: Native update is using a crm entity form and expose that form in the portal. i can't help you if you don't have a specific question, you need something like a design for your implementation. I advice you to read a lot of portals and a lot of CRM365

Comment: Managed to use the native update if it is one record I am updating, but not when I need to do bulk update.

I have an entity list where I tick the records I want to update, select a value from a date picker and want to click a button and update the selected records.

My problem is I don't know how I'm going to send the value of the selected date from the portal to the CRM Workflow